# SparkJava returns application/octet-stream instead of text/html

Tags: java, spark-java

I followed [this](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/lessons/deploying-spark-apps-to-heroku) tutorial and faced with some issues. When I deploy my project to Heroku and go to the page i.e. `myapp.herokuapp.com` it only downloads the executable(when I run it in Chrome it's just an html page with no css etc.). The same happens if I run it localy

here is the log

> 2016-11-21T20:50:20.869829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./build/install/myapp/bin/myapp` 2016-11-21T20:50:23.113910+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
>   2016-11-21T20:50:23.129449+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>   2016-11-21T20:50:23.601125+00:00 app[web.1]: 257 [Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @464ms
>   2016-11-21T20:50:23.821081+00:00 app[web.1]: 478 [Thread-0] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - == Spark has ignited ...
>   2016-11-21T20:50:23.821187+00:00 app[web.1]: 479 [Thread-0] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:40917
>   2016-11-21T20:50:23.824781+00:00 app[web.1]: 482 [Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.3.6.v20151106
>   2016-11-21T20:50:23.950381+00:00 app[web.1]: 608 [Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4293e16d{/,null,AVAILABLE}
>   2016-11-21T20:50:23.974973+00:00 app[web.1]: 632 [Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@63da5e33{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:40917}
>   2016-11-21T20:50:23.975263+00:00 app[web.1]: 633 [Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @846ms
>   2016-11-21T20:50:24.611542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

The same log appears locally. If I run `gradle :run` works as expected. Procfile contains `web: ./build/install/myapp/bin/myapp`

**EDIT:**

So I tried opening my webapp in Mozilla and it showed me that the HTTP response is the type of `application/octet-stream` . I assume I there is something to do with Spark

Comment: What executable? Are you setting a Content-Type header? the logs show no errors.

Comment: `build/install/myapp/bin/myapp.bat`. yes, in index.html there is `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` The log shows no errors, but instead of showing html file the browser downloads some executable file which if I run it in chrome it opens an html file with no css and etc.